# Getting an array of all 1 character long substrings of a given String using split

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String sub="0110000";
    String a[]=sub.split("");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

I get the output as

```
[, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Why is the first element null?
How can I get an array without null at the beginning?

Comment: Why don't you use "0110000".toCharArray() and iterate through the chars? Or was the question as a matter of interest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument is actually not null, it is the empty string `""`. The reason why this is part of the output is that you split on the empty string.

The documentation of split says

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string.

Each position in your input string starts with an empty string (including position 0) thus the split function also splits the input at position 0. Since no characters are in front of position 0, this results in an empty string for the first element.

Try this instead:

```
String sub = "0110000";
String a[] = sub.split("(?<=.)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The pattern `(?<=.)` is a ["zero-width positive lookbehind"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches an arbitrary character (`.`). In words it says roughly "split on every empty string with some character in front of it".

Comment: Well, that may be correct, but it's not obvious why there is an empty string at the start. It would seem equally plausible that there are (an arbitary number of) empty strings between each letter and at the end. Why is the beginning distinguished in this way?

Comment: Added an explanation for that.

Answer (score 5):

It's a quirk off `String#split` the string it takes is actually a regular expression which matches the empty string that is at the beginning of your input.

try `toCharArray()` instead:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String sub="0110000";
    char a[]=sub.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

I'll leave it as a exercise for the reader to convert the `char[]` array into `String[]`

Comment: *exercise for the reader to convert the char[] array into String[]* I wonder why though. I don't see the point of using an array of 1char strings rather than a char[]. +1, BTW

Comment: I agree, but just realised that the guy asked for an array of String's from a String, not an array of char's from a string

Answer (score 2):

It's not null, it's an empty string. That's an important distinction!

You can get what you want by using this construct:

```
 String[] tokens = "0110000".split("(?<=.)";
 // the (?<=.) means that there must be a character
 // before the match, hence the initial empty string won't match
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens)));
```

But I don't think that's a good idea. I can't imagine why you want to split a String into an array of one-letter Strings. You probably should use this instead:

```
char[] chars = "001100".toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because "" matches at the beginning of the string. It also matches at the end, but `split()` discards the trailing empty string.

Answer (score 0):

A String **always** start with an empty string. An empty string contains no characters. You can check the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334129/get-string-array-from-a-string).

Comment: That question was extremely similar ;)